# How can I make an FTP-only user with a particular home directory?

Tags: ftp

I have a directory called  `/backups` where all backups are stored for all users with a dated folder.

Now, I want to make one FTP user so that when he connects via ftp, he goes straight into that folder to download those backups.  How can I do that?

In whm/cpanel i have pure-ftpd installed.

I don't want to make a account for that user like i have website for each user but something by which that user can download those files.

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual user account on pure-ftpd.

```
pure-pw useradd USERNAME -u ftpuser -d /backups -m
```

- Note that ftpuser is the user profile that the FTP process will run as once the user logs in. Essentially it is a "skeleton" profile for the user account. This makes it easier to configure permissions based on real groups which apply to your virtual users.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to make a user outside of cPanel's control, make sure that the UID and GID are outside of the range that cPanel uses (should be able to determine that range pretty easily by looking at /etc/passwd and /etc/group).  Have a read of `man useradd` to find out how to create user accounts.

Are you trying to set this up so that you can copy the backups to a remote location?  If so, cPanel already has functionality to write the backups to a remote FTP server.

Comment: Actually i am making backups using shell scripts not cpanel backups.
I want to download the backups to my home company local server once a week so thats if i have FTP account i can download the backups easily